# know the type of network (2G, 3G, 4G) in a javacard application

Tags: java, javacard

I am developing a javacard applet and I need to know the type of network to which the phone has been connected (2G, 3G, 4G), does anyone know if that can be done with any javacard or java method?
Thank you.
Regards
Jorge

Comment: That kind of information is not known by the Java Card even through the (U)SIM API to my knowledge, so I guess that the SIM card should be told the data connection type. But as I'm not sure other than by browsing the API, I'll not answer.

Comment: Thanks. I got to get the network through Provide Local Information command.

Comment: Great! That's one of the reversed commands used in SIM right? You can answer your own question to help others find it, I'll be happy to upvote!

Comment: Or you can remove your question, but please don't leave it hanging like this.

Comment: Sorry i don't saw your answer, For know the network wich the phone is connected i have used a Provide Local information command with Device Identities equal "06", in TS 102 223 you can see Provide Local Info and that the value '06' for Device Identities is Access Technology. When this command with this value reaches the phone it will return the network to which it is connected in the tag Access Technology, if this value is equals '00'=2G, '03'=3G, '08'=4G.

Comment: It's not an answer, these are comments below your question. You can answer by pasting your comment into the answer box. Then we can do things like upvote so you can gain more reputation. You can also accept your own answer after a while, to indicate that the issue has been resolved. That way other users can benefit from the info provided.

Answer (score 1):

For know the network wich the phone is connected i have used a Provide Local information command with Device Identities equal "06", in TS 102 223 you can see Provide Local Info and that the value '06' for Device Identities is Access Technology. When this command with this value reaches the phone it will return the network to which it is connected in the tag Access Technology, if this value is equals '00'=2G, '03'=3G, '08'=4G